# General 'map' function for Scala tuples?

Tags: scala, tuples, contravariance, superclass

I would like to map the elements of a Scala tuple (or triple, ...) using a single function returning type R.  The result should be a tuple (or triple, ...) with elements of type R.

OK, if the elements of the tuple are from the same type, the mapping is not a problem:

```
scala> implicit def t2mapper[A](t: (A,A)) = new { def map[R](f: A => R) = (f(t._1),f(t._2)) }
t2mapper: [A](t: (A, A))java.lang.Object{def map[R](f: (A) => R): (R, R)}

scala> (1,2) map (_ + 1)
res0: (Int, Int) = (2,3)
```

But is it also possible to make this solution generic, i.e. to map tuples that contain elements of different types in the same manner?

Example:

```
class Super(i: Int)
object Sub1 extends Super(1)
object Sub2 extends Super(2)

(Sub1, Sub2) map (_.i)
```

should return

```
(1,2): (Int, Int)
```

But I could not find a solution so that the mapping function determines the super type of Sub1 and Sub2.  I tried to use type boundaries, but my idea failed:

```
scala> implicit def t2mapper[A,B](t: (A,B)) = new { def map[X >: A, X >: B, R](f: X => R) = (f(t._1),f(t._2)) }
<console>:8: error: X is already defined as type X
       implicit def t2mapper[A,B](t: (A,B)) = new { def map[X >: A, X >: B, R](f: X => R) = (f(t._1),f(t._2)) }
                                                                    ^
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: X
 Note: implicit method t2mapper is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
       implicit def t2mapper[A,B](t: (A,B)) = new { def map[X >: A, X >: B, R](f: X => R) = (f(t._1),f(t._2)) }
```

Here `X >: B` seems to override `X >: A`.  Does Scala not support type boundaries regarding multiple types?  If yes, why not?

Comment: This looks like a case for HLists. See for example http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-6e-hlist%C2%A0apply/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
implicit def t2mapper[X, A <: X, B <: X](t: (A,B)) = new {
  def map[R](f: X => R) = (f(t._1), f(t._2))
}

scala> (Sub1, Sub2) map (_.i)                             
res6: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

A more "functional" way to do this would be with 2 separate functions:

```
implicit def t2mapper[A, B](t: (A, B)) = new { 
  def map[R](f: A => R, g: B => R) = (f(t._1), g(t._2)) 
}       

scala> (1, "hello") map (_ + 1, _.length)                                         
res1: (Int, Int) = (2,5)
```

Answer (score 5):

I’m not a scala type genius but maybe this works:

```
implicit def t2mapper[X, A<:X, B<:X](t: (A,B)) = new { def map[A, B, R](f: X => R) = (f(t._1),f(t._2)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), although you'll have to define the mapping function first before doing the map:

```
object fun extends Poly1 {
  implicit def value[S <: Super] = at[S](_.i) 
}

(Sub1, Sub2) map fun // typed as (Int, Int), and indeed equal to (1, 2)
```

(I had to add a `val` in front of `i` in the definition of `Super`, this way: `class Super(val i: Int)`, so that it can be accessed outside)

Answer (score 0):

The deeper question here is "why are you using a Tuple for this?"

Tuples are hetrogenous by design, and can contain an assortment of very different types.  If you want a collection of related things, then you should be using *...drum roll...* a collection!

A `Set` or `Sequence` will have no impact on performance, and would be a much better fit for this kind of work.  After all, that's what they're designed for.

Comment: For my purposes collections are too flexible because of their variable number of elements.  This piece of code is part of an internal DSL written in Scala, where I want to ensure at compile time that the user specifies functions that process exactly 2 arguments (tuples).  Furthermore, if I would use collections instead of tuples in my closure definitions, they would get more verbose, since I cannot use pattern matching ("case (a,b)") anymore.

Comment: Regarding pattern matching: You can match on collections: List(1,2,3) match { case List(a,b,c) => ... } .

Comment: @mkneissl: True, but then you lose type safety wrt number of elements: `List(1,2,3,4) match { case List(a,b,c) => ... }` fails at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For the case when the two functions to be applied are not the same

```
scala> Some((1, "hello")).map((((_: Int) + 1 -> (_: String).length)).tupled).get
res112: (Int, Int) = (2,5)
```

The main reason I have supplied this answer is it works for lists of tuples (just change Some to List and remove the get).